# Modeling Json field without key

Tags: json, node.js

I've a Json like this to modeling:

```
{
  "Anno": 2016,
  "Codice": 131,
  "data": {
    "86072": {
      "CodArticolo": "13",
      "DesArticolo": null
    },
    "86073": {
      "CodArticolo": "10",
      "DesArticolo": null
    }
  }
```

Fields 'Anno' and 'Codice' are given (statically), but I can't navigate 'CodArticolo' and 'DesArticolo' because the key nested into 'data' is variable (I don't think it's a key); the only way is for example data['86072'].CodArticolo. I can't iterate the data "elements" because it isn't an array. I can't redesign the structure of the Json object and I'm using NodeJs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate an object:

```
for (var key in obj.data) {
    console.log(obj.data[key]);
}
```